# How do I stop changing the current songs after "selecting" a track in Media Browser? (foobar2000)

Tags: foobar2000

I am using the newest version of foobar2000 (as seen in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTsu0.png)). Whenever I click on any folder in the media browser on the left, the window on the right immediately starts showing the files from that folder --> I lose the current playlist, and I don't know how to get it back.

I would like the programme to ignore the fact that I clicked on something (once, NOT TWICE) in the Media Browser, and leave the section on the right as it is. Is that somehow possible?

Thanks for the answer in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of a single click can't be changed for this component (Album List). You might want to try other library viewers such as [Facets](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_facets), which allows to change single click behavior.

Answer (score 0):

These 4 playlists are used by foobar directly:

1. History
2. Library view
3. Library viewer selection
4. Filter Results

When you get some songs you want in one of these playlists, you can just rename that tab (just right click on the tab).

Now when you click some music on the left it will create a new tab.

Get into the practice of creating lots of playlists with whatever you like. Copy things from those 4 folders to your own custom playlists and foobar won't touch that.

Also there are a lot of foobar plugins(components) you can install for playlists.

eg., each search you do will create a new playlist automatically.

Check https://www.foobar2000.org/components